# What are Amanchu's uniforms inspired by?

Tags: amanchu

The first time I saw uniforms of this kind was when I was watching Amanchu.

[image: Hikari in uniform]

Are there any Japanese schools which use this kind of uniform?

Comment: Answering the title, it looks a bit similar to [Aria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_(manga)) which was written by the same author. Answering the question body, seems there's no school with this kind of uniform.